# MAX + Left Function Excel

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I am trying to get the max value of a column based on the `Left` function

What I am doing is the following :

[image]

These are the results I get when i write this into column C :

```
=MAX(LEFT(A:A, 2))
```

But what I truly want is to get in column C the max value of all column A not for each cell.

So the result should be in this case 90 for all rows.

What should be the formula here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update 2

Here is another solution which I think is better than my original (below)

```
=INT(SUMPRODUCT(MAX(SUBSTITUTE(A:A,"-",".")*1)))
```

it can be entered as normal (just <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

---

---

## Orignal Answer

You need *numbers* and *arrays*

```
=MAX(IFERROR(LEFT(A:A,2)*1,0))
```

Let's break this down. Multiplying by turns your strings into **numbers** - since `Left` only returns a string

```
LEFT(A:A,2)*1
```

Unfortunately this method returns `#Value` if you multiply an empty string by `1`. You will definitely have some empty strings in the range `A:A` so we wrap the whole thing with an `IFERROR` function.

```
IFERROR(LEFT(A:A,2)*1,0)
```

Now we still need excel to treat this as an array (i.e. a whole column of numbers, rather than just one number). So we put the `MAX` formula in and enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The result is that the formula looks like this in the formula bar

```
{=MAX(IFERROR(LEFT(A:A,2)*1,0))}
```

which would return `90` in your example, as required

---

## Update 1

If you are using Excel 2013 or later, you can also use the `NUMBERVALUE` function

```
=MAX(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A:A,2)))
```

again, enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: FWIW,  Array type formulas should limit the references to the data itself and not use full column arrays.  If the data set is significant ant there are many formulas entered it will slow down the calc times.  For each formula entered it will do over 1 million calculations.  That can turn into a lot if this formula is dragged down a few hundred lines.

Comment: Agreed. Good advice!

Comment: Updated with a non-CSE option as well

Answer (score 5):

Just another option that gets entered normally:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,--LEFT($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A)),2),1)
```

[image]

Array formulas will calculate the enitre referenced array.  So care should be taken to limit the number of iterations to only the data set.

The `$A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A))` part of the formula does that.  It finds the last cell in column A with data in it and sets that as the upper bound.  So in this instance the reference range is A1:A3.  But, it will grow dynamically as data in Column A is added, so no need to change the formula each time data is added.

Comment: Nice way to do it without an array formula

Comment: @RobinMackenzie it is an array type formula and must abide by array formula limitations, but it does not get entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  It is similar to SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: Yep - what I meant is - nice way to do it without Ctrl+Shift+Enter