# Max + Left + Find/Lookup Function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make a formula that will find the maximum value in a column using the left function, but only for cells which contain a serial date value matching today's serial date value.

[Formatting of the data in the column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYgrJ.png)

Based on the example data, the result of the formula should be 12, because today's serial date value is 44755, and the cell with the highest matching serial date value is 12. This is the formula I currently have, which I found in an [older post looking for a similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570474/max-left-function-excel).

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,--LEFT(Database!$H$1:INDEX(Database!$H:$H,MATCH("ZZZ",Database!$H:$H)),2),1)
```

It finds the maximum value perfectly, so in the example above it would return 15. But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to only consider cells that have the matching serial date value without breaking the formula.

Please let me know what you think.
Thanks!

Comment: According to the similar solution you linked to, this is the range/array: ```$A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A))``` which you may want to try replacing with the FILTERed array of your interest. For the filter criteria might need to use the similar expression as in LEFT() but with RIGHT() to extract the serial date value. Feel free to post your formula if you still have open issues.

Comment: I put this into an answer. Have a look and feel free to confirm/upvote if it solved your question or advice if something is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I understood your question:

(in cell B1 is the formula from your link)

[image]

This is the formula (cell C1):

```
=LET(vBase;$A1:INDEX($A:$A;MATCH("ZZZ";A:$A));vLeft;LEFT(vBase;2);vRIGHT;RIGHT(vBase;5);vFiltered;FILTER(vLeft;vRIGHT=TEXT(TODAY();"0");"no such date");AGGREGATE(14;6;--vFiltered;1))
```

Might need to replace `;` with `,` due to regional settings

Comment: Just implemented it, and it works perfectly! Thanks again.